# #define Glib::string std:wstring

Tags: c++, typedef, c-preprocessor

I have Linux code and I want to port it to Windows. The code uses `Glib::ustring`, but I want to replace all the strings to `std::wstring` for testing purposes.

Is there a way to define all `Glib::string` to `std::wstring` without changing it in code? Something similar to `typedef` or `#define`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes you think that `Glib::ustring` is interchangeable/interoperable with `std::wstring`? Most likely if you made that substitution you'd just get a bunch of compiler errors, or if you're unlucky it would compile and run with different semantics.

I think you're going to have to bite the bullet and convert your Linux code to use `wstring` first and then the Windows port should be a lot less complicated.

That said, assuming you don't need `Glib` in the Windows version you could remove all references to that and then create your own fake type in a header:

```
namespace Glib
{
    typedef std::wstring ustring;
}
```

Comment: I am not doing any string operations; I am just checking if it matches with another hard-coded string. I could simply use std::string as well.